# CSV malformed error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

Heres my code

```
  task priceupdate: :environment do
    csvtoopen = open('')
    csv = CSV.parse(csvtoopen, :headers=>true, quote_char: "\x00")
    csv.each do |row|
Stuff to do here
    end
  end
```

I've got an issue, heres the error code:

```
CSV::MalformedCSVError: Unquoted fields do not allow \r or \n (line 28010).
```

Any ideas why this isn't running?

Sam

Comment: how did you come up with the quote_char? this is the zero byte but your data obviously has `"` quotes?

Comment: Hi there, I left it in because it was another fix for an error!

Answer (score 0):

The csv file is valid (but it starts with a UTF-8 [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)).

All fields are quoted, so you really need to use `"` as `quote_char`.

Now the parser thinks you have multiline fields and since they are not 'quoted' (with `\x00`) you get an error.

Comment: so i changed the character from `\x00` to `'""` and i got this error `CSV::MalformedCSVError: Illegal quoting in line 1.`

Comment: sorry i mean `'"'`

Comment: @samnymr12 That's probably due to the UTF-8 BOM: your file starts with the 3 bytes 0xef 0xbb 0xbf. So you may need to tell your parser that a BOM is present (or perhaps open in UTF-8 mode).